# Jquery sortable drag and drop not showing 'move' cursor

Tags: jquery, css

Im using this .sortable function on my list. My problem is that I want it to show the move cursor when the drag and drop is being used, and the pointer cursor only on hover. I have my css calling the cursor:pointer on hover, but it does not seem to show the move cursor at all. Everything else works fine. Code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blah.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        /*helper: 'clone', Tried this =(*/
        distance: 5,
        delay: 300,
        opacity: 0.6,
        cursor: 'move',
        update: function() {}
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Seperate css doc contains:

```
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.1em; line-height: 18px; height: 18px; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }

/* HERE'S THE IMPORTANT STUFF! */
#sortable li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#sortable li.ui-sortable-helper {
    cursor: move;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. =)

Perhaps a little more information. Its a db populated list from a while statement. each list item is a link, so I want it to display the {cursor: Pointer;} option. But when it is dragged i need it to display the {cursor: move;}. I would have thought that the code above would do it but its not working. I confused myself with the first post so thought i would clarify this a little better.

Comment: you can edit your question and add the additional information rather than adding it as comments. Comments are more for others to ask you for more information to help them answer.

Comment: Done that — you can remove the comment if you get a chance.

Comment: Sorry still new to this site. =)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that your CSS setting is used across all states.

You can get around this by setting the cursor for "dragging" as well via CSS:

```
#contentLeft li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#contentLeft li.ui-sortable-helper{
    cursor: move;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mWYEH/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. =) I shall tell tales of you to my grandchildren.

Comment: Ok it seems I was wrong. Its not working any more. I have edited the above post with what I have (mockup version for test). Can you see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nope, seems alright to me and works if I test it. You're possibly overriding the styles in a different place. Do you have the project online somewhere?

Comment: only local at the moment. I have just tested it in ie, opera, and ff. and it is working as intended now. But not in chrome. yet the jsFiddle works as intended in chrome. For some reason Chrome adds a {cursor: auto;} to the 'body'. Would this be whats affecting it?

Comment: Possible. Try adding an `!important` for a test.

Comment: OK I completely rewrote my css and it seems to be working now. Thank you so much for the help. =)

Comment: Is there any important reason why `cursor: pointer;` is added on `:hover`? It's [usually](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) applied to the stateless rule.

Answer (score 2):

Found a less blunt way to do it:

```
#contentLeft li:not(.ui-sortable-helper) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: FYI for anyone else that may try to use the `:not()`. It's not supported in older browsers if that's a problem for you. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using a [handle](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle) to start dragging:

```
.ui-sortable-handle {
    cursor: pointer
}

.ui-sortable-helper .ui-sortable-handle {
    cursor: move
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:pointer;">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:pointer;">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:pointer;">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Remove from css. Because i also face the same problem. and i just do what i write here

Comment: Please don’t use inline styles, especially not to override styles defined within a stylesheet. The reason that this works is that inline styles have a higher priority. But the solution comes at the price of worse maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$element.droppable({
  over: function() {
    $('body').css('cursor','copy');
  },
  out: function() {
    $('body').css('cursor','no-drop');
  },
});
```

It will indicate the user if the draggable if over a droppable.